# How to hide unwanted updates?

Tags: updates, update-manager

I was wondering for quite some time now; is there any way to hide/remove any unwanted updates when I see some in the Ubuntu Update Manager?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you want to do is to "hold" a package, to prevent it from being upgraded. The ubuntu documentation has [a page dedicated to it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PinningHowto#Introduction%20to%20Holding%20Packages), that will tell you how to hold a package, but with synaptics or the command line, and how to "un-hold" it

Comment: I removed for example gwibber by purge command why are there still packages related to it and then come updates for those packages... p.s. this is just commotion. The software center should be little bit inteleggent.

Comment: @alfalife: there are at least 2 possible reasons for what you see. 1. is that Gwibber is a client-server app (it has a background service and a GUI frontend), and maybe you only removed the frontend? 2. is that maybe you removed part of the application, but not all libraries.  The daemon and some of those libraries might be useful for other applications too, so Software Center has to be careful about what to remove automatically...

Comment: @lmontrieux, that page does describe "holding" from the command line, but not the Synaptic "lock" mentioned in @user4124's answer. Can you explain the difference? Is one better than the other? I expected to see the command line `apt-mark hold` reflected in the Synaptic GUI as a "lock" icon, but it's not.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `Synaptic Package Manager` (already available in Ubuntu) in order to `Lock` the version of the specific packages. Therefore, the packages will not be offered for upgrade. You would need to Lock each individual package in your list.